# Can anyone explain why Re7 is one of the lines suggested by the computer?

Tags: positional-play

I was analyzing a game and got stuck in this position by Re7 move. I do not want to mention the player's name. As seen in the diagram Bc5 is misleading, but Bd6 is one of the lines. Bd6 is OK, but Re7 seems inexplicable to me. Please anyone can explain??

[image: Why Computer suggest Re7 when it is Black to move ?]

Comment: Protecting bishop for case Ne4 Nxe4 dxe4 and having f7 covered is also usefull. Calm position, no need to hurry.

Comment: I think you are correct but for Black already done an exchange sacrifice on e3 he has to attack move by move . He cannot be calm . Meanwhile Ne4 from Black and after the exchanges will open the e-file for White and the Rooks of White are desperate to have such an Open file.

Comment: Calm position doesn't necessarily mean good or equal position. You are just exchange down for long term positional compensation in pawn structure and good bishop. There is absolutely no need to overly press in such a position. You are not rook down. Just target e3, g3, h3, make your king as safe as possible, limit White's play and you can just sit and wait.

Comment: Totally agree to what you said but what about the open file . Why would Black dare to open the file with Ne4 exchange .

Comment: @hoacin, you should submit it as an answer. I would up vote it.

Comment: @SethProjnabrata Please pay attention to the position...dxe4 is a fork by the pawn on the queen and the rook. Re7 protects the bishop. If ...Ne4 straight away, Qxd7 threatening Qxe8+. Therefore Re7 is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protecting bishop for case Ne4 Nxe4 dxe4 and having f7 covered is also useful. Calm position, no need to hurry.